# Constrained optimization problem written as minimax Lagrange

Tags: mathematical-economics, optimization

I am reading a note on moral hazard and it shows that a problem like $\max _{s(x)} \mathbb{E}[V(x-s(x))]$ s.t. $\mathbb{E}[U(s(x))] \geq \bar{H}+c\left(a^{*}\right)$  can be solved by setting up a simple Lagrangean $$\min _{\lambda} \max _{s(x)} \mathcal{L}=\mathbb{E}\left[V(x-s(x))\right]-\lambda\left[\bar{H}+c\left(a^{*}\right)-\mathbb{E}[U(s(x))]\right]$$.

I guess this is a way to solve the non-equal constraint but I cannot understand the meaning of the minimax intuitively. And I wonder is there any difference of solving this minimax Lagrange comparing to solving the normal Lagrange FOCs and checking the complementary slackness conditions?

Comment: I am just guessing but I think they want to emphasize that they want to minimize value $\lambda$. If I remember correctly my graduate math classes, it is actually not proper to say that when you optimize the Lagrangian function you are taking the derivative wrt $\lambda$ when you use the constraint as a foc, maybe they want to emphasize that you should do that now

Comment: This is the saddle point property of the Lagrangian---see any intro text on static optimization. Informally, $\lambda$ in the indirect marginal utility, and as usual, it should be minimized at the maximum (if the problem is well posed, say under convexity). If constraint is slack, $\lambda = 0$ which is the minimum value possible ($\lambda \geq 0$ is a constraint); this is just complementary slackness rephrased.